# how can I get an id from request.POST of the form that I'm submitting now

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-forms

I'm building a clinic Management System
and in the section that you add a new doctor, I want the admin to be able to add the days that the doctor is available at, so that means the days' field is a list but Django doesn't have a list field in its models so I created CharField-> days
 `days = models.CharField(max_length=200,null=True)`
and then I've created a multi-select input field inside the form

```
 <select name="days" class="form-select" multiple aria-label="multiple select example">
        <option value="mon">Mon</option>
        <option value="sun">sun</option>
        <option value="wed">wed</option>
       <option value="etc">etc</option>
      </select>
```

so I took the Selected data by using this code

```
for i in request.POST.getlist("days"):
    d= str(i)+" "+d
    print(d) # result gonna be the days in string value splited by spaces  eg : mon sun wed
```

so I can use it later by using split() but the thing is I'm not able to add this data into the form while submitting it so I thought that I can save the form data and then alter the field days
like that

```
def add_doctor(request):
    form = Add_doctorForm()
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = Add_doctorForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            d = ""
            for i in request.POST.getlist("days"):
                d= str(i)+' '+d
            print(d)
            formdata = Doctors.objects.get(id = request.POST.get("id")
            formdata.days = d
```

but the problem is request.POST does not contain any data about the id cuz the id takes its value from the database so the post request do not know the id
so can anyone help me to find another way to fix this problem?

Answer (score 0):

It very much depends how your form is defined.

If you have a [`ModelForm`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/forms/modelforms/) then this shouldn't be an issue so I assume you didn't go down that path.

So in the non `ModelForm` case I'd suggest the following approach:

- Add a hidden input in your form to store the id of the doctor in question, i.e. use a [`HiddenInput`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/forms/widgets/#hiddeninput) in your form and fill that with the id of the doctor when presenting the form.
- Then you can get this via the form and retrieve the doctor in question (you access the data via `request.POST` but you can/should get it via [`cleaned_data`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/forms/api/#django.forms.Form.cleaned_data) which is available after you called `is_valid()`).

Comment: I've tried that but the thing is I didn't know how to give the doctor id and how can I get it if the entry takes the id from the database so the entry needs to be imported before adding the days value so that's why I wanted to get the id of the entry after saving it and then adding the days to it as an update

Answer (score 0):

I got it now, I don't need to get the id from the request.POST
I can just get the latest id in the database and then +1 so that will be the id of the current doctor
just like that

```
c_id = int(Doctors.objects.latest('id').id)+1
```

and that's it
thank you Yvesonline you inspired me to think about another way to get the id value thank you for helping me .